# Issue with Javascript boolean values

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I wrote a small script to recreate the Chrome address bar, wherein my code checks an input for any domain extension(.com, .edu etc.) and sets a boolean flag to true if an extension is found.
It then checks the flag and based on the result opens the website or sends it to google as a query.
Additionally, if it is a website, it checks if the string contains http:// and www. and if not, adds it to the string before using Window.Open() to open the target.

What's wrong here?

```
function openSite(){
     var domain_extensions = [".aero", ".asia", "...All Other Extensions...", ".zr", ".zw"];

        var isSite = false;

        var userIn = document.getElementById('in_field').value; //Retrieves Textbox code

        for (var i=0; i < domain_extensions.length; i++)
            if (userIn.search(domain_extensions[i]) !==-1)
                isSite = true;
                        //Checks against the array of extensions

        if (isSite === true){
            if (userIn.search("http://") === -1 || userIn.search("https://") === -1)
                {if(userIn.search("www.") === -1)
                    userIn = "http://www." + userIn;
                 else
                    userIn = "http://" + userIn;                        
                }

                window.open(userIn, '_blank');
                //if extension is found, open website
                        //if qualifier http:// or https:// and/or www. not found, append and open website               
            }

        else{
                var str = encodeURI("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + userIn);
                window.open(str, '_blank');

            } //Searches query for common extensions; if not found search google
    }
```

Comment: What's not happening?  And why is JavaScript's "truthiness" relevant?

Comment: Why are you using `http:`backslashbackslash and not `http://`? Also, you may want to use `break;` in your for loop, although I don't think that would fix anything

Comment: If you add a break, be sure to also add curly braces...

Comment: @Ian Oh damn! That fixed a bit of my issue. Now websites work.

Comment: @contactmatt Even when I type a non-site in, the truth block still executes.

Comment: By truth block, you mean the if(isSite === true)?  That shouldn't be a problem with JavaScript truthiness, but rather how the flag is being set.

Comment: What does the search method do?  Is that custom or native JavaScript?

Comment: @contactmatt See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: Is it possible that some javascript function somewhere adds -1 to my array prototype, which causes my boolean isSite to become true every time?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but I'd use this kind of setup: http://jsfiddle.net/BncKD/ . You can configure it to also test for `www.` being there too, but I don't think it's necessary/right

Comment: @Ian It took me a while to understand, especially all the escape sequences and other characters, but thanks. :)

Comment: @VaibhavGupta Sorry about that - that part was something I found from Googling (and really wasn't the important part). It was just a Regular Expression to validate a URL. From there, you use logic to determine what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem, I believe, with your usage of the [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) function. This function takes a  regular expression as its argument. The `.` character is special in regex, and matches any character.

For example:

```
var test = "blasdfahsadfcomasdfasd";
console.log(test.search(".com")); // prints 11
```

Prepend the `.` with a backslash in order to override this behavior:

```
var test = "blasdfahsadfcomasdfasd";
console.log(test.search("\\.com")); // prints -1
```

Additionally, if you want to check only at the end of a string, add a `$` symbol at the end of the strings like so:

```
var test = "blasdfahsadf.comasdfasd";
console.log(test.search("\\.com$")); // prints -1; prints 12 w/o the $
```